# Access Map's sObject field

Tags: apex

I'm trying to access Map's sObject field value directly from the map, which gives me the error saying that the Net_Amount_Funded__c does not exist:

```
Map<Id,SObject> lenderMap = new Map<Id,SObject>();
System.debug(lenderMap.get(lenderId).Net_Amount_Funded__c);
```

Error:

```
 "compileProblem": "Variable does not exist: Net_Amount_Funded__c",
```

If I do

```
System.debug('lenderMap.get(opp.Id): ' + lenderMap.get(lenderId));
```

I get the debug without issues, but I need to access directly to a field of that sObject

```
07:49:07.39 (67969824)|USER_DEBUG|[39]|DEBUG|lenderMap.get(opp.Id): Lender__c:{Name=Lender-071649, Amount_Due_Merchant__c=4500.00, Amount_Expected__c=5046.00, Amount_Financed__c=6000.00, Amount_Financed_Down__c=6000.00, Amount_Funded__c=0.00, Amount_Returned__c=0.00, App_ID__c=UMC00281672, Covered_Approved__c=1, Discount_Fee_USD__c=0.00, Discount_Fee_Percent__c=0.00, Discount_to_UMC__c=15.90, Gross_Revenue__c=546.00, Interest_Rate__c=30.01, Loan_Information__c=Application is onboarded successfully and webhook has been sent, Loan_Status__c=Lender Approved, Loan_with_Applicant_1_or_2__c=1, Max_Amount_Approved__c=6000.00, Merchant_Discount__c=25.00, Merchant_Discount_USD__c=1500.00, Net_Amount_Funded__c=0.00, Payment__c=335.51, Percent_Revenue__c=9.10, Platform_Fee_Received__c=0, Primary_Signer__c=User 123, Term_In_Months__c=24, Opportunity__c=0064X00002J3QYtQAN, Id=a1Q4X000004FP93UAG}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with the `SObject` type, you need to use the `.get()` and `.set()` methods.

So the following would work

```java
System.debug(lenderMap.get(lenderId).get('Net_Amount_Funded__c'));
```

Do note that SObject's `.get()` returns an `Object`, so you'll need to do explicit type-casting if you want to actually *use* the result anywhere (other than just feeding it into SObject's `.set()`, that is).

Answer (score 2):

When you have `SObject`, you cannot statically reference any fields on it except `Id`. Instead, you need to do `get(field)`, which gives you back an `Object`. Alternatively, the simpler approach is to make it `Map<Id, My_Object__c>`, which then obviates the problem that you are getting a generic `SObject`. Typing it out in more detail below.

**What you're doing currently**

```
Map<Id, SObject> records = new Map<Id, SObject>(...);
SObject record = records.get(someId);
Object value = record.Some_Field__c;
system.debug(value);
```

**Static casting instead**

```
Map<Id, My_Object__c> records = new Map<Id, My_Object__c>(...);
My_Object__c record = records.get(someId);
Decimal value = record.Some_Field__c;
system.debug(value);
```

**Dynamic get instead**

```
Map<Id, SObject> records = new Map<Id, SObject>(...);
SObject record = records.get(someId);
Decimal value = (Decimal)record.get('Some_Field__c');
system.debug(value);
```